# Capture iPhone camera using QuickTime

Tags: iphone, quicktime

Can I capture audio and video signals from iPhone's camera and microphone in a web application using QuickTime ? If not, does exist any other method in which I can capture the video and audio from iPhone cam & mic. from a web app. and not an iPhone native app.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

http://almaer.com/blog/iphone-web-applications-and-the-record-api

and this

https://labs.ericsson.com/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers

you can get some code on github:

http://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap

The codes are very helpful for your purpose

Comment: None of these use QuickTime and by none of the method doesn't seem to be affordable for transmitting the a/v signal to a server for example.

Comment: Apps like UStream use native apis to do the job, I don't think you can do it via web API